# CSS list marker not inline with text

Tags: css, list, marker

I played around with `::marker` which is supported by all major browsers.

When changing the font size I noticed that the marker / bullet is not inline with the text. With inline I mean that the top of the bullet should be inline with the top of the text.

I tried resetting paddings and margins without luck.

Is there a way to fix this without making the bullet smaller and still use the `::marker`?

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 4rem;
}

li::marker {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Chocolate bar chocolate bar sweet roll caramels oat cake marzipan chocolate apple pie shortbread. Halvah donut jelly beans pie liquorice brownie gummi bears marzipan cotton candy. Cake pudding bonbon liquorice sweet roll.</li>
  <li>Chocolate bar chocolate bar sweet roll caramels oat cake marzipan chocolate apple pie shortbread. Halvah donut jelly beans pie liquorice brownie gummi bears marzipan cotton candy. Cake pudding bonbon liquorice sweet roll.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: inspect the ::marker element to notice the issue. You will have better luck defining your custom bullet instead of relying on the default one

Comment: `li` and `::marker` both have default `line-height: normal`, which means it is based on their respective `font-size`. As the `li` has `font-size: 16px` and the `::marker` has `font-size: 5rem` there is a difference in height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the moment, there is no way to specify `::marker`'s `padding` or `margin`. According to the spec, the [allowable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker#allowable_properties) are:

- all [font-properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Fonts#properties)
- `white-space`,
- `color`
- `text-combine-upright`, `unicode-bidi` and `direction`
- `content`
- all [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations#css_properties) and [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions#properties) properties.

Anything else is not supported, at least for now. You can't use `margin`, `padding`, `position`, `top/left/...`.

If you need more control over your markers, use `list-style-type: none` and either use `:before` (works for most use cases) or simply prefix the contents of each `<li>` with a `<div class="marker"></div>`, which gives you full control:

```css
li { list-style-type: none; }
li>.marker {
  /* go wild... */
}
```

---

Example:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
li {
  padding-top: .5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
li:before {
  font-size: 5rem;
  margin-top: -.5rem;
  content: '•';
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex: 0 0 .6em;
  line-height: .4em;
  padding-right: .2em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Chocolate bar chocolate bar sweet roll caramels oat cake marzipan chocolate apple pie shortbread. Halvah donut jelly beans pie liquorice brownie gummi bears marzipan cotton candy. Cake pudding bonbon liquorice sweet roll.</li>
  <li>More chocolate.</li>
  <li>Chocolate bar chocolate bar sweet roll caramels oat cake marzipan chocolate apple pie shortbread. Halvah donut jelly beans pie liquorice brownie gummi bears marzipan cotton candy. Cake pudding bonbon liquorice sweet roll. Chocolate bar chocolate bar sweet roll caramels oat cake marzipan chocolate apple pie shortbread. Halvah donut jelly beans pie liquorice brownie gummi bears marzipan cotton candy. Cake pudding bonbon liquorice sweet roll.</li>
</ul>
```